# JS typewriter animation writes <br> literally

Tags: javascript, html

I've "made" a typewriter (pure) JS animation:

```
<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = "Hello, <br>this is the rest of the text blablabla";
var speed = 50;

function typeWriter() {
if (scrolling) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  }
 }
```

I want multiple lines, but the function writes <br> literally. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a new line character and not `<br/>` as text in order to prevent the browser from encoding the text. The best thing to do is to use `\n` to generate line breaks.

If you are editing on a `<div>` or `<span>` you will need the `white-space: pre;` rule. Textareas do not require this CSS rule.

Demo: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/abNoROY

Comment: Oh my god that fix was so simple! I had tried adding \n, but didn't add `white-space: pre;`. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you add HTML code char by char, but you should add HTML tags as a whole. Otherwise the browser sees just the `<` character and corrects it with `&lt;`. You can either add all chars to `>` when you approach the opening `<` but a simpler solution will be to replace `<br>` with a single new line character `\n` and replace it with `<br>` during "printing":

```js
var i = 0;
var txt = "Hello, \nthis is the rest of the text blablabla";
var speed = 50;
var scrolling = true;

function typeWriter() {
if (scrolling) {
  if (i < txt.length) {
    var char = txt.charAt(i);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += char == '\n' ? '<br>' : char;
    i++;
    setTimeout(typeWriter, speed);
  }
  }
 }
 
 typeWriter();
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```